# Unity3D: Gradient vs flat coloured sprites performance

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite

I'm building my game for mobile platforms. I am saving game performance from every possible aspects. 
I believe the flat colours are simple to render as the engine does not want to differ colours per pixel. Does the engine gives performance improvement in flat sprites over the gradient ones?

Thanks.

Comment: both flat and gradient are images or dynamicaly generated by the engine ..

Comment: These micro-optimiziations are usually pretty useless. Most of the cpu/gpu power is spent on game logic, scene rendering, input and audio. It makes exactly zero difference in performance / FPS if a `GameObject` has a `Sprite` which is flat coloured or gradient colored. The GPU drawing code is highly optimized anyway, you won't get into problems there with a 2d game.

Comment: Hi DA.  I've realised we have **absolutely no clue** what sort of project you are doing.  (We don't even know if it's 2D or 3D.)  I would truly urge you to post an image from your project, so that, people have a general idea what engineering paradigms you are facing.  Cheers merry christmas